Gitlab CI: "found unknown escape character" for call command &
I have a simple gitlab config file:
  script:
    - "& $env:P7_TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH\client\p7batch.exe --log-level=error --run $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR\autotest\jobs\_clear.py"

Thats 12th and 13th lines. When I run my pipe the runner gives me that:
`.gitlab-ci.yml`: (): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 13 column 7

I tried to quote the command but it didnt help as you can see...

Is it not the backslash that should be double backslash: P7_TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH\\client\\p7batch.exe ?

think It should be double? But runner doent line the & operator, not backslashes

Could the colon be the problem? A command containing a colon needs to be wrapped in single quotes: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script

I have found that "&" is not good for yaml deserialization, so I tried to replace it with "Powershell" and it has worked out!
